# Does the iPad 2 Support the iPad 1 Dock?

Tags: dock, accessories, ipad

I'm thinking about selling my first generation iPad, but was wondering if I should sell the dock with it. I know that they are coming out with a new iPad dock specifically for the second generation. Will it not fit on the first generation dock?

Comment: I fear you might have to wait until later next week until someone can actually try this :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use the first generation dock, but it's a bit difficult to get the iPad 2 connected, because of the tapered edge: See this [link](http://www.9to5mac.com/55832/ipad-2-works-with-the-original-ipad-dock-ipad-keyboard-dock-still-available-to-order/).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure if the original iPad Dock will work with the iPad 2. Apple is selling an [iPad 2 Dock](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC940ZM/A#overview), however, that is different than the original model.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend waiting to sell the dock.  I would venture a guess that it will, however, not perfectly. eg, I use my iphone edge dock with my iphone 4 and I think it is great!